# App to view clipboard contents on OSX in unformatted / hex form

Tags: macos, clipboard

I'm looking for an OSX application that allows you to view the clipboard data in hex format. So if, for example, there's an image copied to the clipboard, then the app shows me the image data in hex form (i.e., "unformatted")

Is there an app out there for OSX that can do this? [CLCL](http://www.nakka.com/soft/clcl/index_eng.html) works, but unfortunately it's Windows only.

Comment: I assume you're a developer of sorts, so, if no solution shows up, you could try to do it yourself. It should be easy to access the `NSPasteBoard`, get the `NSData` from it and write that to a file. Open with a hex editor and you're done.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Apple has provided sample code in the form of a project to create an app called "Clipboard Viewer" which does exactly what you're looking for. Don't know where I put my copy of the project, but here's a copy of the app:

http://www.markdouma.com/developer/ClipboardViewer.zip

Comment: You're awesome. This is indeed exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This app is now pretty outdated (2009), so try the project from the Apple Developer Site first. It's been updated in 2012 and works a lot better.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to download and compile the code, it's still available in Apple's Developer Site as [Clipboard Viewer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/ClipboardViewer/Introduction/Intro.html).