# Clipboard viewer for OS X that allows extracting the data in any available format

Tags: macos, clipboard

I am looking for a clipboard viewer for OS X which will show *all formats* that the clipboard is holding the data in.  (I.e. something similar to the Clipbook viewer in Windows XP.)

I found a number of programs that show the contents of the clipboard, but I haven't been able to find one which lists all formats available on the clipboard at the moment, and makes it possible to extract either of them.  I believe the OS X clipboard can hold the data in multiple formats simultaneously, just like Windows (e.g. in MS Word there's a Paste special... menu item which allows selecting the format to paste).

Answer (score 15):

You can see the different types by running `the clipboard as record` in AppleScript Editor.

`the clipboard`, `the clipboard as text`, or `Unicode text of (the clipboard as record)` will return a plain text version. AppleScript still converts line endings to CR though.

Comment: `$ osascript -e 'the clipboard as record' | less` for a command line one-liner

Comment: This works, but reports HTML data weirdly encoded: `«class HTML»:«data HTML3C68746D6...` and does not let me check the hex dump along the text easily

Answer (score 5):

The MacOSX developer tools come with an example app called "ClipboardViewer.app" and its source for Xcode.
This is by far the most explicit clipboard exploration tool I've found for MacOSX: it shows the string of the clipboard flavour (called UTI on MacOSX) and a hex dump of the content.

Here is an example screenshot made with this app (using a Mathematica source). It would be cool if such a project could be made into an open-source project for MacOSX instead of being a dev-tool-thing. However, there's a [public web-page of Apple dev support, where you can download the sample project](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/ClipboardViewer/Introduction/Intro.html) and compile it using XCode; as of today (late 2018), one needs to let the suggested be applied such as chaning architecture from 32 to 64 bits; after this all compiles well.

[image: example clipboard viewer usage]

Comment: Where exactly can one find the ClipboardViewer.app source code?

Comment: There are links to the source and binary at https://superuser.com/questions/246714/app-to-view-clipboard-contents-on-osx-in-unformatted-hex-form

Comment: I added the link to the source of clipboard viewer. Thanks @ian-dunn.

Comment: If you have an Apple ID, you can log into the Apple Developer Portal and search for it: https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=clipboard%20viewer - it is part of the "Additional Tools for Xcode" bundle. Note that you don't need a paid developer account for this - the basic one works just fine

Comment: I recently made a presentation about this and could not find a version that was working anymore (all the binaries I had were 32 bits and I had catalina) so I found the free [clipboard viewer of langui](https://langui.net/clipboard-viewer/)  which could do the same service.

Answer (score 5):

https://langui.net/clipboard-viewer/ as [suggested by Paul Libbrecht](https://superuser.com/questions/541335/clipboard-viewer-for-os-x-that-allows-extracting-the-data-in-any-available-forma#comment2364024_1104703) works perfectly!

[image: Clipboard Viewer window screenshot]

Comment: perfect solution for my needs.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to see what types are available, you can run

```
osascript -e 'clipboard info'
```

Example output:

> «class weba», 974, «class RTF », 425, «class HTML», 604, «class utf8», 16, «class ut16», 34, string, 16, Unicode text, 32

Compare this with

```
osascript -e 'the clipboard as record'
```

which might output a mess that doesn’t let you easily see just the types.

> «class weba»:«data weba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», «class RTF »:«data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», «class HTML»:«data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», «class utf8»:Clipboard Viewer, «class ut16»:Clipboard Viewer, string:Clipboard Viewer, Unicode text:Clipboard Viewer